# fetching the variables from an included file inside a loop

Tags: php, foreach, include

Hi,

I need a code that can scan one of my directories and fetch the values in the variables present inside each one of them ($cat and $object).

```
function colindex() {
 $cat=array(1 =>'fruits', 2 =>'vegetables', 3 =>'meat');
 $column = scandir("../content");
 for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
  echo $cat[$x].':<br>';  
  foreach ($column as $value) {
   ob_start();
    include('../content/'.$value); 
   ob_end_clean();
   if($cat==$cat[$x]) {
    echo "{$object}<br>";
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

This is how 1 of these files generally looks

```
<?php
$cat="fruits";
$object="apple";
?>
```

So the output should be

```
fruits:
apple
orange
banana

vegetables:
carrot
lettuce

meat:
beef
lamb
```

this wont work, it redirects me to the root directory for some reason. What seems to be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it redirects me to the root directory"_? Also, you don't need output buffering for this.

Comment: I mean exactly that. Instead of showing me the page with the output it redirects me to Index of /
[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description
[DIR] bin/  2016-10-15 11:25  -   
[DIR] www/  2018-11-07 13:27  -   
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Sounds like a problem that has nothing to do with the code in your question. Monitor your browser's _Network_ console to see what's going on (select the _"Preserve log"_ option)

Comment: like what kind of problem?

Comment: How would I know? You've only shown some PHP code that could not possibly perform any HTTP redirects

Comment: Thats weird because if I put outside the loop then I get the variables right

Comment: If you put **what** outside the `for` loop? Perhaps one of your included files is not what you expect. I would at least check the value of `'../content/'.$value`. It may not be what you think it is

Comment: but even if there is an unexpected kind of file, it should not execute any redirects whatsoever because its inside a ob_start();

Comment: Have you looked in your _Network_ console yet?

Comment: Output buffering does not affect headers set via `header()`

Comment: so if there is a file with a redirect it will execute it regardless?